# Clojure While Loop

Tags: java, clojure, loops, while-loop

I trying clojure i am trying to figure out how to implement the following algorithm,

I am reading from an input stream i want to continue reading until it is not a delimiter character.

i can do this in java with a while loop but i can't seem to figure out how to do it in clojure?

```
while
   read
   readChar != delimiter

   do some processing....
end while
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know Clojure, but it looks that, like Scheme, it supports "let loops":

```
(loop [char (readChar)]
   (if (= char delimiter)
       '()
       (do (some-processing)
           (recur (readChar)))))
```

Hope this is enough to get you started. I referred to http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc9 to answer this question.

NOTE: I know that Clojure discourages side-effects, so presumably you want to return something useful instead of '().

Comment: Right about the side effect. Maybe add an accumulator to the loop to show how a result is built functionally?

Answer (score 6):

Working on Clojure 1.3.0, and for what it's worth, you can write while loops in Clojure now by doing something akin to

```
(while truth-expression
  (call-some-function))
```

Comment: this relies on some side effects to make truth-expression eventually go false.

Answer (score 3):

The loop approach will work fine in clojure however loop/recur are considered low level operations and higher order functions usually preferred.

Normally this sort of problem would be solved by creating a sequence of tokens (characters in your example) and applying on or more of clojure's sequence functions (doseq, dorun, take-while, etc.)

The following example reads the first username from /etc/passwd on unix like systems.

```clj
(require '[clojure.java [io :as io]])

(defn char-seq
  "create a lazy sequence of characters from an input stream"
  [i-stream]
  (map char 
   (take-while
    (partial not= -1)
    (repeatedly #(.read i-stream)))))

;; process the sequence one token at a time
;; with-open will automatically close the stream for us 

(with-open [is (io/input-stream "/etc/passwd")]
  (doseq [c (take-while (partial not= \:) (char-seq is))]
    ;; your processing is done here
    (prn c)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this in the spirit of `line-seq`.  It's fully lazy and exhibits more of Clojure's functional nature than `loop`.

```
(defn delim-seq
  ([#^java.io.Reader rdr #^Character delim]
     (delim-seq rdr delim (StringBuilder.)))
  ([#^java.io.Reader rdr #^Character delim #^StringBuilder buf]
     (lazy-seq
       (let [ch (.read rdr)]
         (when-not (= ch -1)
           (if (= (char ch) delim)
             (cons (str buf) (delim-seq rdr delim))
             (delim-seq rdr delim (doto buf (.append (char ch))))))))))
```

[Full paste](http://paste.lisp.org/display/82652).

Comment: Gotta be a shorter way 'ta do this.

Answer (score 1):

A while-loop usually involves mutable variables, i.e. waiting until a variable meets a certain condition; in Clojure you'd usually use tail-recursion (which the compiler translates into a while-loop)

The following is not quite a solution, but this variation of the for-loop might be of help in some cases:

```
(for [a (range 100) 
      b (range 100) 
      :while (< (* a b) 1000)] 
    [a b]
  )
```

This will create a list of all the pairs of a and b **until** `(< (* a b) 1000)`. That is it will stop as soon as the condition is met. If you replace :while with :when, they you can find **all** of the pairs that meet the condition, even after it finds one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I came out with this version:

```
(defn read-until
  [^java.io.Reader rdr ^String delim]
  (let [^java.lang.StringBuilder salida (StringBuilder.) ]
    (while
      (not (.endsWith (.toString salida) delim))
      (.append salida (str (char (.read rdr))))
    )
    (.toString salida)
  )
)
```

It looks for a String, not a single char as delimiter!

Thanks!